# How to write a SQL query that concatenates multiple rows from the input table into one row in the output table

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following sample table:

```
C1     C2      C3
=================
A      21      S
A      22      S
A      23      S
A      24      T
B      25      S
B      26      S
```

How can I write an SQL query to give the following output:

```
COL1   COL2       COL3
======================
A      21,22,23      S
A      24            T
B      25,26         S
```

For all rows in the input table where C1 and C3 are the same, I want one row in the output table that has all the C2 values concatenated, comma separated.

I'm working with an Oracle database.

Comment: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Comment: Maybe this SO question will help; [Concatenate many rows into a single text string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)?

Comment: I just realized I never came back to post the results.   @MarcB pointed me in the right direction, here's my final result:  SELECT C1 AS COL1, LISTAGG(C2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C2) AS COL2, C3 AS COL3 FROM TBL GROUP BY C1,C3;    http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73cc9/19/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using oracle 11g

```
SELECT 
     C1, 
     LISTAGG(C2, ',') as C2,
     C3
from 
     tbl 
GROUP BY 
     C1,C1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be a database specific answer, so please what db you are using.  Mysql is popular, so here is the Mysql5 answer:

```
select col1, group_concat(col2 SEPARATOR ','), col3 from tbl group by col1,col3;
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL, you can use [Group_Concat](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/). For example:

> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Language) As Languages FROM CountryLanguage WHERE CountryCode = 'THA';